# Rails, turbolinks and inline javascript. How to avoid duplicate event handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-5

I have read many posts on the internet, but in the end I still haven't found a nice solution to deal with Turbolinks + inline scripts.

Turbolinks does give a nice feeling and I don't really want to stop using it, but in some cases I have a hard time debugging duplicate event handlers.

I have some views with inline javascript : I actually prefer having the (small) javascript codes near the element(s) that are interacted with, saving only big javascripts functions for app.js.

So imagine I have a search page with several filters, but only on that specific page. When the user changes the search filters, it is supposed to GET (using remote/AJAX) the new results. The easiest way was to introduce

```
$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function() {
  // Submit on every change
  $('#myform input').change(function() {
    $('#myform').submit()
  }
})
```

When navigating with turbolinks and going back to the search page, I naturally end up with several duplicate bindings on every select, causing multiple form submits.

I have tried adding

```
$('#sidebar-search input').unbind()
```

Just before the `.change()` line but it doesn't seem to work, and for some reason the form is still posted several times : once with AJAX, several other duplicates (that thankfully are cancelled) and another non-remote request (my server replies with HTML).

Using turbolinks 5

[image]

Comment: Your JS has unbalanced curly braces – it is missing a `}`. But since you’re not noticing a syntax error, maybe that was just a bad copy-paste.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to avoid this problem when using inline JavaScript. The section of the Turbolinks README “[Working with Script Elements](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#working-with-script-elements)” advises avoiding inline `<script>`s when installing event handlers:

> Turbolinks evaluates `<script>` elements in a page’s `<body>` each time it renders the page. You can use inline body scripts to set up per-page JavaScript state or bootstrap client-side models. To install behavior, or to perform more complex operations when the page changes, avoid script elements and use the `turbolinks:load` event instead.

It sounds like the reason you prefer inline scripts is the convenience of having relevant JS and HTML next to each other. This is a matter of workflow. While I’m afraid I don’t know any way to make separate JS files as convenient as inline JS, you can make it close by putting a comment in the HTML where the JS used to be, saying “this template has JS that is only for it”. When you are editing a template, if you see that comment, open the corresponding JS file in a horizontal split in your editor, so you can view both files at once. If you are using an editor that supports opening paths in files, you could even write the path to the JS file in the comment so you can open it just by following the link.

You have various choices for organizing which files your single-page JS snippets go in. You could put them in per-controller JS files like `products.js`, or the global file `application.js`, or you could create a new global file `single_page_js.js`. Then you could put comments above each section, labeling which template that code affects. Alternatively, you could also use some sort of naming convention to match JS files to templates. For example, when writing event handlers for the template `app/views/products/index.html.erb`, you could put the JS in `app/assets/javascripts/products_index.js`.

The ideal for you would be some sort of plugin that preprocesses your HTML templates to remove `<script>` elements, copies their contents to the global JS file, and adds wrapping code that ensures that that bit of JS is only run once, when the page is first visited. But I don’t know of any such plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I used todo like this, and never had any issue with turbolink except disabled for specific links.

```
function run_after_turbo(){

  $('#myform input').change(function() {
    $('#myform').submit()
  }

}
$(run_after_turbo);
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", run_after_turbo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved switching to plain js

// Old

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-toggle="submenu"]', function(event){                                                                              
  $(this).next('ul.submenu').slideToggle();                                                                                                     
    return false;                                                                                                                                 
});
```

// new

```
var subMenus = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-oggle="submenu"]');
  subMenus.forEach(function(subMenu){
    subMenu.addEventListener('click',function(event){
      $(subMenu).next('ul.submenu').slideToggle();
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

So in your case should be like this

```
   var form = doucument.querySelector('#myform input');
form.addEventListener('change', function() {
    $('#myform').submit();
});
```